# does salesforce "extended mail merge" feature offer functionality?

Tags: salesforce, mailmerge

I would like to add functionality to the extended mail merge feature on salesforce,
Does anybody know if I can add some apex code to it? Or if it already has built in functionality I could use to apply a template based on the value of a field?

Thank you in  advance :)

Comment: I have seen apps on the app exchange like Conga composer ( https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016b7FEAQ )and drawloop (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016Zn3EAE)

Comment: Both offer workflow. My question is how can automation/workflow be applied/developed using some apex code.